# Comparar campo com multiplos valores de outro campo

Tags: php, sql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de fazer um SELECT baseado em multiplos valores do campo [jainscrito] e listar somentes os IDs que nao consta no campo [jainscrito]

estou tentando sem sucesso

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email <> '$email' AND  id NOT LIKE jainscrito ";
```

no caso se o usuario id=18 so podera listar id 20

Comment: Pela sua pergunta não da pra entender ao certo o que quer fazer. Poderia detalhar mais?

Comment: quero listar os ID da tabela que não consta no campo JAINSCRITO @Francisco

Comment: Se você usa uma versão maior que 5.7 do MySQL, mude o tipo de dados do teu campo `jainscrito` para o tipo JSON e assim você conseguirá manipular nativamente os valores dentro dele.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, você quer fazer algo deste tipo:

```
$sql = "select * from usuarios where email <> '$email' and ( select concat( '.', jainscrito, '.') from usuarios where email = '$email' ) not like concat( '%.', convert(id, char(5)), '.%') ";
```

Verifique se isso te atende.